# Anypoint Studio (Eclipse) on Windows 7 with multiple users

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, mule-studio

I'm trying to create a Windows 7 VM that can be used be developers to do various development work.  I've installed Anypoint Studio, and I find that each of the user's workspaces is visible to all of the other users, and in fact the workspace launcher defaults to the last used workspace.  Is there a way around this?  I.e., when user A logs in, user A can only use user A's workspace?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way that Eclipse works on Windows, it will happen with any IDE based on Eclipse.

I believe what you can do, probably not the best, is to have an installation of Studio in a folder inside of the user profile, so each user will have it's own installation.

Or, probably better, you can create an specific shortcut for each user and in the shortcut you can add the command line to open an specific workspace.

You need to add -data your_workspace_location

And be sure that each workspace is saved in a user profile directory, so the rest of the users will not have OS permissions to access that folder, but that depends on how you create the users and the permissions in your Windows.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That did it.  I used `C:\AnypointStudio\AnypointStudio.exe AnypointStudio.exe -data %UserProfile%\AnypointStudio\workspace` as the target.  Thanks!